using cubejs with elasticsearch
I want to use Cube.js with Opensearch which is forked version of elasticsearch 7.x. I managed to establish the connection, but I couldn't find resources regarding the syntax. Are there people who use Cube.js with Elasticsearch properly?
i creted environment file as above
CUBEJS_DB_URL=http://localhost:9200
CUBEJS_DB_USER=***
CUBEJS_DB_PASS=***
CUBEJS_DB_ELASTIC_QUERY_FORMAT=json
CUBEJS_DB_ELASTIC_VERSION=7
CUBEJS_DB_ELASTIC_OPENDISTRO=true
CUBEJS_DEV_MODE=true
CUBEJS_DB_TYPE=elasticsearch
CUBEJS_API_SECRET=***
CUBEJS_EXTERNAL_DEFAULT=true
CUBEJS_SCHEDULED_REFRESH_DEFAULT=true
CUBEJS_SCHEMA_PATH=model

and simple cube
`cube(`Tasks`, {   sql: `SELECT \* FROM tasks\`,

preAggregations: {
// Pre-aggregations definitions go here
},

joins: {
// Joins definitions go here
},

measures: {
count: {
type: `count`,
drillMembers: \[accountId, createdDate\]
}
},

dimensions: {
accountId: {
sql: `account_id`,
type: `number`
},

    createdDate: {
      sql: `COALESCE(${CUBE}.created_date, '1970-01-01')`,
      type: `time`
    }

},

dataSource: `default`,
});\`

when i hit the run query on cubejs panel. i am getting an error.
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
